# PHP increase date by 7 hours

Tags: php, date, time, directory, glob

it's working okay so far, but I want to increase the modified date by 7 hours.  This means it will be in line with my timezone.  I've searched the internet for answers but can't seem to get it working.  The date I want to increase is the '$fileDate'.  Here's my code so far:

```
<?php 

// list from a given folder $folder="test/";
$folder = "../";
$files = glob($folder."*jpg*" ); // to avoid hidden files

// Sort files by modified time, latest to oldest
//array_multisort(array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),SORT_NUMERIC,SORT_DESC,$files);


// Use SORT_ASC in place of SORT_DESC for oldest to latest
array_multisort(array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),SORT_NUMERIC,SORT_ASC,$files);

// display the file names 
print("<table>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>File Name</td>
        <td align='center'>Last Modified Date</td>
    </tr>");
if(count($files)){
    for( $i=0 ; $i < count($files) ; $i++ ){
        print("<tr>");
        print("<td>".basename($files[$i])."</td>");
        $fileDate = date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($files[$i]));
        print("<td>".$fileDate."</td>");
        print("</tr>");
    }
}
print("</table>");
?>
```

Comment: Dont you think that only the line with `$fileDate` will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$fileDate = date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($files[$i])+ (60*60*7));
```

To increment it, add the corresponding number of seconds you want to add. 7 hour = 60*60*7

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$filetime_nf = filemtime($files[$i]) + 25200;
$fileDate = date("F d Y H:i:s", $filetime_nf);
```

It increases the file date time for seven hours and stores it as a variable, and then it formats it with the date function.